# call model relation function in controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model

In my Model I have the function

```
App\Akte.php
public function lvs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\lvs', 'lv_id');
}
```

In my Controller I call

```
public function index()
{
    $aktes = \App\Akte::all();

    return view('admin.akte.index', ['aktes' => $aktes]);
}
```

And i´d like to extend my collection $aktes with the lvs table.  Can somebody explain how to do this?

So my result should be a collection in which every single element of "Akte" has its Many collections of lvs in it..

Comment: Just look the doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: That is really not what i´m looking for, sadly..

Comment: In the link a 'find()' or similar is required. I wish to have the same result but for each item in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also want the relationship loaded, just use:

```
$aktes = \App\Akte::with('lvs')->get();
```

Comment: Great! Worked just fine!Thanks a lot

Comment: this is an important feature but I can barely find it in the laravel doc. what a shame

Answer (score 0):

See that. May be usefull for your needs.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

```
public function index()
{
    $aktes = \App\Akte::->all()->where('lvl', 2);

    return view('admin.akte.index', ['aktes' => $aktes]);
}
```

somthing like this ...